# Using JS to add a background color to a dynamically created Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening,

I am having trouble using a click event listener to change the background color of a js created div.

I have trolled through the questions but I am stumped as to why , even if I declare the function after the divs have been created an appended it still does not change the color.

The code is below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<style>
</style>
<script src="script.js" defer > </script>
<body>

  <h1> Grid aye? </h1> 

  <div class="wrapper">
  
    <aside class ="toggleBar"> This is where the switches will go </aside> 
  
    <!-- This where the grids are created, using psuedo classes in CSS. -->
    <div id="container"></div>

    
  
  </div> 


</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const gridItem = document.getElementById("grid-item"); 


// uses a loop to create the required divs 
function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);


function changeGridColor (e) {
  e.style.backgroundColor="red"; 

}; 

gridItem.addEventListener(`click`,changeGridColor());
```

Can anyone point me to where I have gone wrong?

I tried declaring the event listener before appending the created divs, but that throws errors in VSCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solution is correct that the element does not exist by then. However, if you added more rows, those new rows/grid items will not have the event listener attached.

Instead, you can rely on a more versatile event delegation technique to ensure that all future grid items have the event listener:

```
// uses a loop to create the required divs 
function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);

  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.classes = ['grid-item'];
    cell.style.setProperty('height', '24px');
    cell.style.setProperty('background-color', 'black');
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};

makeRows(16, 16);


function changeGridColor (e) {
  e.style.backgroundColor="red"; 
}; 

 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.target.classes);
    if(e.target && e.target.classes.includes('grid-item')){
          changeGridColor(e.target);
     }
 });
```

We add the `grid-item` class and then setup a click event listener so that whenever a grid item class is clicked, the color is changed.

Here's a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1e7c2gzu/22/

(Also note you wouldn't see your grid items initially because they didn't have a size to them so I added a size and set them to black so you could see them)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, i was using CSS to assign the height and width props to the grid-items class, but this seems a much better way, so thanks for that. I shall set the original props upon creation and remove the CSS.

Comment: Ah gotcha - if you already have a css class on `.grid-item` then I would recommend sticking with the css class for that and not doing the height and background-color setting lines I did! The key thing here was the general event listener anyway.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help, and taking the time. It works much better now, will make a note of the help and the differences between the code. Never thought to use the if statement to ensure that the function fires on the correct Div !

Answer (score 1):

```
const gridItem = document.getElementById("grid-item");
```

This line will not be correct because no element in your HTML has `grid-item` as Id **at this moment of the script execution**.
You will need to put this line after the `makeRows(16, 16);`.

In addition, in `container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";`, you add a **class**, **not an id**. So `const gridItem = document.getElementById("grid-item");` will not be correct and need to be `const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item")`.

Because there are multiple div with this class, you will need to loop over them in order to attach the event listener. Instead of `gridItem.addEventListener(`click`, changeGridColor);`, you will need :

```
const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");

for(let gridItem of gridItems) {
    gridItem.addEventListener(`click`, changeGridColor);
}
```

EDIT: and `e.style.backgroundColor = "red";` should be `e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: I knew it was something to do with the creation of the divs, but that just did not register. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Venex: Also, be careful with perenthesis. in `gridItem.addEventListener(`click`,changeGridColor());` you are passing `undefined` to the eventListener registration because the execution of `changeGridColor` does not return anything. -- Without the parens, it is a function reference, not a function call. ;)

Comment: No problem, I add one correction in edit :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. Although still having problems getting the changeGridColor() function as using the changeGridColor (e), does not actually change the color.